# Cannot understand why this Haskell code works so fast

Tags: haskell, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

In my attempt to learn Haskell,
i have written the following piece of code to solve a classic optimization problem.
The problem at hand is to compute the sales maximizing prices, where the price is monotonically increasing,
given a sequence of i buyers, each of which will buy at a maximup price of v_i.
In mathematical terms:
given  [v_i] , find [p_i] s.t. p_{i+1} >= p_i that maximises \sum_i q(v_i,p_i)
where q(a,b)=0, if b>a, q(a,b)=b b<=a

I have implemented the following code, solving the problem using what i think is a top-down dynamic programming approach.
The algorithm decides at each step whether it will increase the price, by maximising all over the remaining sequence

```
maxP::Int->[Int]->(Int,Int)
maxP p [] = (0,p)
maxP p q 
   | a<p = (fst (maxP p (tail q)),p)
   | a==p = (p+fst (maxP p (tail q)),p)
   | otherwise =(maximum l,p+argmax l)
     where a=head q
           pc=[p..a]
           l=zipWith (+) pc $ map (fst)  ( map ((flip maxP) (tail q)) pc )
```

The code is -as expected when using Haskell- an almost 1-1 implementation of a DP algorithm.
The code returns the ( Sales Sum,Price Level)

And, in order to have all the price sequence, a function is called for all [v_i]

```
maxPI::Int->[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
maxPI a [] b = reverse b
maxPI a c b = maxPI q (tail c) (q:b)
     where (p,q) = maxP a c
```

I have also implemented helper functions

```
argmax::[Int]->Int
argmax x = mP x (-1) 0 0

mP::[Int]->Int->Int->Int->Int
mP [] maxi pos cpos = pos
mP a maxi pos cpos
     | ((head a)> maxi) = mP (tail a) (head a) cpos (cpos+1)
     |otherwise = mP (tail a) maxi pos (cpos+1)
```

Obviously, the function could (should) be optimized, to use only  one run of the algorithm over the list
But my question is that, even without the aforemention optimization, the algorithm runs surprisingly fast.
So my question is the following:
Why this algorithm works so fast?

Am i simply mis-understanding the complexity of the DP algortihm?
Does Haskell employs a by default memoization of the function maxP?

Furthermore,  i dislike my Haskell-ness of my code. Could you please make any suggestions?

I was expecting a much slower performance

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing how long you thought it "should" have taken. Keep in mind, though, that Haskell programs aren't simply compiled as a group of functions that call each other. It can do a lot of what you might consider "inlining", but to a greater degree than simply adding, e.g., the definition of `maxP` to the definition of `maxPI`. For example, even though `map ` is defined recursively as `map f (x:xs) = f x : map xs`, the compiled code is essentially just a while loop. *You*, the Haskell programmer can't write imperative-style code, but the *compiler* can do so safely.

Comment: A quick style suggestion: don't use `head` and `tail`. You're already doing pattern matching for the empty list; also use pattern matching to get the head and tail when the list is non-empty.

Comment: I don't think you have implemented a DP algorithm here. There will be identical subcomputations in `maxP` that are recomputed rather than shared. This is completely separate from the problem you mention about `maxPI` calling `maxP` multiple times.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thats my main -algorithmic- concern as well. That the recursion computes multiple times the same thing, and -following the answer- without tabulating the result. So the algorithm seems exponential. It is a considerable reduction from the combinatorial naive approach -my feeling is that it is a DP since it recursively reduces the maximum problem to subproblems - but still the algorithm seem to execute faster than it should. But probably i don't understand quite well the workings of a DP algorithm

Comment: Why do you believe it is not exponential? At least here it appears to be quite cleanly exponential; `maxP 0 [5,10..45]` (40.4s) takes 13x as long as `maxP 0 [5,10..40]` (3.2s), which takes 13x as long as `maxP 0 [5,10..35]` (0.25s). And I will state my case more strongly: this is *not* a DP algorithm. It has the shape of one, but you've missed out the key sharing mechanic that makes DP useful. So being surprised by this program should not lead you to any conclusions about DP algorithms, especially not that you don't understand their runtime.

Comment: Ok. Thnx for the polite clarification. Is indeed exponential. My error was that, as you point out, the tabulation is critical for sub exponential runtime. A recursive solution of a Belmann Equation is not enough,

Comment: I have added a DP algorithm to my answer, so that you can get a feel for how such algorithms might idiomatically be implemented in Haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why your intuition about how fast it should be is wrong. But I'll answer the concrete questions you have that don't require me to live inside your head:

> Does Haskell employs a by default memoization of the function maxP?

Haskell, the language, has no opinion on whether `maxP` should be memoized or not by language implementations. GHC, the most popular implementation, will not memoize `maxP` as it is written here.

> i dislike my Haskell-ness of my code. Could you please make any suggestions?

I have a few suggestions. The most obvious one is to use pattern-matching instead of `head` and `tail`. Like this:

```
maxP::Int->[Int]->(Int,Int)
maxP p [] = (0,p)
maxP p (a:as)
   | a<p = (fst (maxP p as),p)
   | a==p = (p+fst (maxP p as),p)
   | otherwise =(maximum l,p+argmax l)
     where pc=[p..a]
           l=zipWith (+) pc $ map (fst)  ( map ((flip maxP) as) pc )

maxPI::Int->[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
maxPI a [] b = reverse b
maxPI a c@(_:ct) b = maxPI q ct (q:b)
     where (p,q) = maxP a c 

mP::[Int]->Int->Int->Int->Int
mP [] maxi pos cpos = pos
mP (a:as) maxi pos cpos
     | (a> maxi) = mP as a cpos (cpos+1)
     |otherwise = mP as maxi pos (cpos+1)
```

You have quite a few extraneous parentheses. Sometimes that can be useful for readability, but they're not really doing it for me in this situation.

```
-           l=zipWith (+) pc $ map (fst)  ( map ((flip maxP) as) pc )
+           l=zipWith (+) pc $ map fst (map (flip maxP as) pc)
-     | (a> maxi) = mP as a cpos (cpos+1)
+     | a>maxi = mP as a cpos (cpos+1)
```

In `maxP`, you can use `compare` to compute all three guards at once.

```
maxP::Int->[Int]->(Int,Int)
maxP p [] = (0,p)
maxP p (a:as) = case compare a p of
   LT -> (fst (maxP p as),p)
   EQ -> (p+fst (maxP p as),p)
   GT -> (maximum l,p+argmax l)
     where pc=[p..a]
           l=zipWith (+) pc $ map fst (map (flip maxP as) pc)
```

Your computation of `l` can be done more clearly with a single `map`, or via list comprehension.

```
-     where pc=[p..a]
-           l=zipWith (+) pc $ map fst (map (flip maxP as) pc)
+     where l=map (\p' -> p'+fst (maxP p' as)) [p..a] -- OR
+     where l=[p'+fst (maxP p' as) | p' <- [p..a]]
```

You could consider computing the index of the maximum value and the maximum value itself in the same traversal, and reuse existing library functions, like this:

```
   GT -> (maxv,p+maxi)
     where l=[p'+fst (maxP p' as) | p' <- [p..a]]
           (maxv, maxi) = maximum (zip l [0..])
```

This `argmax` will return the latest maximum, unlike your solution, which returns the earliest maximum. I'm not sure whether that matters. If it does, you could use [`Arg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Arg) to avoid using the index in the comparison or [`Down`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Down) to use it "the other way".

You mention `fst (maxP _ as)` a couple times. Might be worth doing a DRY thing there.

```
maxP::Int->[Int]->(Int,Int)
maxP p [] = (0,p)
maxP p (a:as) = case compare a p of
   LT -> (go p,p)
   EQ -> (p+go p,p)
   GT -> (maxv,p+maxi)
     where l=[p'+go p' | p' <- [p..a]]
           (maxv, maxi) = maximum (zip l [0..])
           go p' = fst (maxP p' as)
```

Actually, reading more carefully, it occurs to me that the whole `p+maxi` computation you're doing is just to recover the `p'` value you already have in hand! So, better:

```
   GT -> maximum [(p'+go p', p') | p' <- [p..a]]
```

I keep twisting myself in knots over this last bit. Is that the same as `maximum [maxP p' as | p' <- [p..a]]`? Anyway, at this point, it's clear now that the `EQ` and `GT` cases are actually doing the same thing. So let's merge them. We'll move back to guards now, actually, hah!

```
maxP::Int->[Int]->(Int,Int)
maxP p [] = (0,p)
maxP p (a:as)
   | a<p = (go p,p)
   | otherwise = maximum [(p'+go p', p') | p' <- [p..a]]
     where go p' = fst (maxP p' as)
```

In `maxPI`, there's no real reason to build up the list backwards and `reverse` when you can just build it forwards to begin with.

```
maxPI::Int->[Int]->[Int]
maxPI a [] = []
maxPI a c@(_:ct) = q:maxPI q ct
     where (p,q) = maxP a c
```

This can probably be done as a scan, though I'm a bit less confident of this transformation.

```
maxPI::Int->[Int]->[Int]
maxPI a cs = scanl (\a' cs' -> snd (maxP a' cs')) a (tails cs)
```

I'm not sure I love that change, but it's one to be aware of. All told, that leaves us with this code:

```
maxP::Int->[Int]->(Int,Int)
maxP p [] = (0,p)
maxP p (a:as)
   | a<p = (go p,p)
   | otherwise = maximum [(p'+go p', p') | p' <- [p..a]]
     where go p' = fst (maxP p' as)

maxPI::Int->[Int]->[Int]
maxPI a cs = scanl (\a' cs' -> snd (maxP a' cs')) a (tails cs)
```

This feels like pretty idiomatic Haskell to me. If you want to go up from here, you need to start thinking about algorithmic changes, not style changes.

Here's what it might look like to tweak this algorithm so that it shares computations appropriately, i.e. is a dynamic programming solution. First we define a type for tracking the info we're interested in, namely, a minimal price the current solution applies for, the payout we can get assuming we always pay more than the minimum, and the actual prices we should offer to get that payout.

```
import Data.List

data Path = Path
    { payout :: Int
    , minPrice :: Int
    , prices :: [Int]
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

We'll name some simple operations on these table entries. The first is to extend the current table entry under the assumption that we demand the minimum price from the current customer, given the maximum price the current customer is willing to pay.

```
demandMin :: Int -> Path -> Path
demandMin maxPrice path = path
    { payout = payout path + if curPrice <= maxPrice then curPrice else 0
    , prices = curPrice : prices path
    } where
    curPrice = minPrice path
```

The second operation expresses our preference on payouts. It takes two entries in our table and picks the one with a better payout. If we were being robust, we'd also take the smaller minimum price, but we're going to arrange that the first argument always has the smaller minimum, so we can cheat and always take that.

```
maxPayout :: Path -> Path -> Path
maxPayout p p' = if payout p >= payout p' then p else p' { minPrice = minPrice p }
```

With these operations in place, we can write our table-update operator. Each column of our table has an entry for each possible minimum price, and we will assume the incoming column has them in order of lowest minimum price to highest. Given that, we can fill in the next column to the left by, for each row, taking the better of demanding the current minimum price or whatever excellent plan the row below came up with. Like this:

```
maxPayouts :: Int -> [Path] -> [Path]
maxPayouts maxPrice = scanr1 maxPayout . map (demandMin maxPrice)
```

Now, to run the algorithm, we can just initialize our rightmost column, then iteratively fill in columns to the left, finally taking the top-left element of the table as our answer. We have to set up the assumed invariant that rows come in sorted order, but otherwise there is almost no code to write here. So:

```
top :: [Int] -> Path
top prices = head $ foldr maxPayouts [Path 0 price [] | price <- sort prices] prices
```

Try it in ghci:

```
> top [1,2]
Path {payout = 3, startingPrice = 1, prices = [1,2]}
> top [1,3]
Path {payout = 4, startingPrice = 1, prices = [1,3]}
> top [2,1]
Path {payout = 2, startingPrice = 1, prices = [1,1]}
> top [3,1]
Path {payout = 3, startingPrice = 1, prices = [3,3]}
> top [1,5,3]
Path {payout = 7, startingPrice = 1, prices = [1,3,3]}
> top [1,7,3]
Path {payout = 8, startingPrice = 1, prices = [1,7,7]}
```

(Generally you will not care about the `startingPrice` field, but it's easier to just return it than to make a fresh data type that doesn't have it to return.)

It scales well; for example, `top [5,10..1000]` returns essentially instantly for me even without compiling or optimizing. Theoretically it should scale approximately as O(n^2), with n the length of the input list, although I didn't attempt to verify this empirically.

Comment: Thanks for the code suggestions, and for the compiler insights. Quite right about pointing out the difference between lang specification and compiler implementation. Is there another Haskel compiler that would auto tabulate the results of the function?As to the performance, my feeling is that the algorithm remains exponential -specifically as the compiler does not tabulates - and therefore would not be able to handle n>10 or n>15... This seems to be my inadequate understanding of DP algorithms.

Comment: Thnx a lot for you code. I struggle to understand it -as said before- new to Haskell, but i see now a clean, and very Haskell,  implementation of a DP scheme for solving the problem (bottom up?). If i understand it correctly, we could  also  initialize the column using   sort (nub prices) instead of sort price to get an overall complexity of O(nk) where k is the different prices?

Comment: @GrigorisL. Yes, if you expect there to be lots of duplicates, that could be worthwhile. The precise asymptotics you get is actually really interesting. If you sort first, then remove duplicates, you get O(nk+nlog(n)), whereas if you remove duplicates first you get O(nk) (because removing duplicates is O(k^2) and k<n, followed by sorting which is O(klog(k)) and log(k)<n). This is one of those rare situations where I suspect the choice with the better asymptotics will actually perform worse for many practical inputs (provided you use something better than `nub` for removing dupes).